# Segment Fault with vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, c, vector, matrix, segmentation-fault

So I have my code below. I am paneling a matrix/or pgm image. By paneling I mean repeating itself in a set number of columns and rows.  It will look like one of those windows with the panes all separating each glass section.

an example: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_OLskT-GO5VE/TGqgrSX_o_I/AAAAAAAAA-4/vcCdn6hA3fI/s320/2007_12_warhol_cambell_soup.jpg this is a 4x8 matrix of soup cans (which in themselves are a giant matrix of pixels.

I believe the segment fault is happening somewhere with index=k involved, but I can't find anything wrong.  I am re-sizing the matrix so that shouldn't be it.

edit: fixed example.

```
void panel(vector <VecofInts> &p, int inputRow, int inputColumn)
{
    int i, j, v = 1, g = 1, k = 0, row, col;

    row = p.size();//obtaining the original rows
    col = p[0].size();//obtaining the original columns

    p.resize((r * row)); //sets up the new matrix so I can add new elements.

 /* This is my first test loop for the columns; I know I can create a single loop
 for rows and columns but this will help me find problems more easily */

    while(v < c){
        ...
    }

/* this is the loop I'm having trouble with */

    v=1;

    while(v < c){
        k = row;
        while(g < r){
            for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
                k = k + i;
                for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
                    p[k].push_back(p[i][j]);
                }
            }
            g++;
            k++; //this allows the g<r loop to continue and k not repeat itself
                   //in the first i loop again.
        }
        v++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to compile it with the flag -g and run it with a debugger like gdb, this gives yoiu the exact lne of code, where the segfault occurs. See http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html

Comment: where variable "c" is defined?

Comment: I have to do a work around for the debugger.  I will update along the way

Comment: You made no check at all to see if p is empty.  `col = p[0].size();`.  If p is empty, then this is undefined behavior.

Comment: I have checks in the main procedure. sorry, if this seems mysterious, it is a fairly long program.

Comment: can you explain better what is your input and what is your expected output?

Comment: Honestly, the check for p being empty should be in the panel function, not strewn all over other parts of your code.  This way, panel() can in no way enter that loop unless the preconditions are met, i.e. the vector has to be populated.

Comment: @TrickyNicky - I don't get it.  You want copies, vector has operator = to make a copy of itself.  Why are you writing such loops for this?  All you need is to loop and apply operator = to the next row, not loop through each cell.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> x(10,vector<int>(10)); x.push_back(x[9]);`  That copies the entire row 10 to the newly allocated row 11.  No loops are necessary to go through each entry in x[9].  Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Velthune my expected input would be from the command line: "PANEL" to name my function I want to call and then the parameters r and c.  for the rest of the method, I have to use a reference of p to change it and that will be the only thing that gets printed. So I must change the actual format of the original matrix.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie could you walk me through the x(10,10) statement.

Comment: I changed the comment to correctly do the initialization.  The second parameter is a vector<int> with all the values initialized to 10.  I could have just showed this to make it easier: `vector<vector<int>> x(10); x.push_back(x[9]);`.  But the issue is that you have an entire row already set up, and you want to copy it to the new row, you *don't* loop to do this -- just copy it to the new row using operator =, or create the new row from the existing row (as my example shows).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ahh I see this is much easier. However, if I am dealing with 1000 elements in each vector, would this be tolling memory wise and would it be slower?

Comment: @TrickyNicky - So you think that a loop that you write would run faster than the code from the persons who implemented the vector class for your compiler?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Haha going to have to say nope on that one. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example is not too clear what are your intentions.
By the way, I suggest this general approach:

```
typedef std::vector<int> VecofInts;
typedef std::vector<VecofInts> Matrix;
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator RowIterator;

void panel(const Matrix& m, int inputRow, int inputColumn) {
    const int column = m.size(); /* Number of column, each colum is a vec of int */
    RowIterator it;
    for(int i=0; i != column; i++) {
       it = m[i].begin();
       /* m[i] represent a row on your matrix */
       for(; it != m[i].end; it++) {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `k = k + i` in the for loop you will get k = 0,1,3,6,10,15...

I think your purpose is `k++` ?

EDIT:

Please see the comment for `k = k + i`:

```
while(v < c){
    k = row;
    while(g < r){
        for(i = 0; i < row; i++){
            k = k + i; // ####### k = (row), (row+1), (row+3), (row+6), (row+10),(row+15)....
            for(j = 0; j < col; j++){
                p[k].push_back(p[i][j]);
            }
        }
        g++;
        k++; //this allows the g<r loop to continue and k not repeat itself
               //in the first i loop again.
    }
```

Comment: Wont it exit from k, when the For(i) loop exits? and I have k = row; again to reapply the base value so it wont iterate none stop.

Comment: @TrickyNicky  What is `p[k]` stands for?  and actually you got series of p[row+0].push, p[row+1].push, p[row+3].push, p[row+6].push, p[row+10].push in your code

Comment: @TrickyNicky - You know what the maximum value of k must be, but you're relying on faulty logic to exit the loop.  Keep it simple -- why not just check to make sure that k is within bounds, and if not, then you have a problem (or exit the loop).

Comment: @Jerry_Y p[k] is stepping through the main vector that contains the vector of integers.  But row+n will only rely on row in the for(i<row) loop right?

Comment: @TrickyNicky Now I'm confused. Let's assum row=4,  then this k would be 4, 5, 7, 10. Is this what you expect?